# Select sin estilo

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Tengo un select hecho con Bootstrap-Vue que se ve de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código para el `select` es este:

```
  <b-form-group id="input-group-3" label="Select" label-for="input-3">
    <b-form-select
      id="input-3"
      :options="options"
      required
    ></b-form-select>
  </b-form-group>
```

Alguien sabe porque no se aplica el estilo que aparece en la [documentación](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) de Bootstrap-Vue?

Comment: habria que ver si todos los estilos estan bien importados.. el resto de las cosas de bootstrap se ve bien?

Comment: Si @gbianchi, es el único elemento que no se muestra bien.

Comment: ¿Y cuando lo inspeccionas con el navegador y miras su código fuente no aparece nada raro?  ¿que clases le pone a ese select?

Comment: Como se ve en la pregunta, no le he añadido nada, es el mismo código que el de la documentación. No veo nada "raro" en el navegador.